# How do I turn the ringer on for incoming calls?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

How do I turn the ringer on for incoming calls for the Sprint iPhone version 7.0 model MD146LL/A? I've already tried going under settings to sounds.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way I think, Is the Mute button on the left turned down, turn it up
Other thing can you play music from the speakers? If no then there is a problem with the Speaker.